# overwrite file (not append) in c++

Tags: c++, file

I need to modify code written in c++. The code opens a file `authfile` and writes 49 bytes to it. In case the file already exists, I need to make sure the existing data will be overwritten.

The original code first deleted the file and then created a new file. For reasons beyond this discussion, I cannot delete the file, I only need to make sure it is empty, before i write new data to it.

Below is the function that writes the data. How can I modify it, so thatexisting content of the file will be overwritten ?

I suppose, I need to tchange the options of popen

```
bool Util::add_mcookie(const std::string &mcookie, const char *display,
    const std::string &xauth_cmd, const std::string &authfile)
{
        FILE *fp;
        std::string cmd = xauth_cmd + " -f " + authfile + " -q";

        fp = popen(cmd.c_str(), "w");
        if (!fp)
                return false;
        fprintf(fp, "remove %s\n", display);
        fprintf(fp, "add %s %s %s\n", display, ".", mcookie.c_str());
        fprintf(fp, "exit\n");

        pclose(fp);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Your program isn't writing to a file, it's running a command and writing to its standard input.

Comment: Open the file for writing and then close it immediately. Opening it in `write` (not `append`) mode will truncate it.

Comment: A simple `std::ofstream` will by default do exactly what you want.  But as Barmar says, your code is never writing to the file anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `popen` to `fopen` and `pclose` to `fclose`. `popen` / `pclose` is for opening / closing a process. Also, it looks like you're creating the process with flags. You just need to give `fopen` the file path